# Create records from a form and edit them in each row of the table

Tags: angular, typescript

I have a Spring Boot application with Angular in which I am creating the methods to `create` and `update` data from the `form`.

This is my `component.ts`:

```
export class ClientsComponent implements OnInit {

  public show = false;
  public filt = false;
  public formNuevo: FormGroup;
  public formFilt: FormGroup;
  public displayedColumns: string[] = ['id', 'first_name', 'last_name', 'phone', 'action'];
  public isNew: boolean;
  public clientId: number;
  public client: Client;
  public clients: Client[];

  constructor(
    public fb: FormBuilder,
    private clienteService: ClienteService,
    private location: Location,
    private route: ActivatedRoute,
  ) { }

  ngOnInit() {

    this.clienteService.list().subscribe(client => {
      this.clientes = client;
    });

    this.formNuevo = this.fb.group({
      id: [],
      first_name: [],
      last_name: [],
      phone: []
    });

    this.route.params.subscribe(params => {
      this.clienteId = +params['clienteId'];
      this.isNew = !this.clienteId;
      if (!this.isNew) {
        this.clienteService.get(this.clienteId).subscribe(c => {
          this.cliente = c;
          this.formNuevo.patchValue(this.cliente);
        });
      }
    });

  }

  back() {
    this.location.back();
  }

  refresh(): void {
    window.location.reload();
  }

  markFormTouched() {
    /*for (let controlName in this.formNuevo.controls) {
      this.formNuevo.get(controlName).markAsTouched();
    };*/

    for (const controlName of Object.keys(this.formNuevo.controls)) {
      this.formNuevo.get(controlName).markAsTouched();
    }
  }

  save() {
    if (this.formNuevo.valid) {
      if (this.isNew) {
        console.log('1');
        this.clienteService.create(this.formNuevo.value).subscribe(cliente => {
          console.log(`New client`);
          this.refresh();
        }, error => {
          console.log(`Error created`);
        });
      } else {
        console.log('2');
        this.clienteService.edit(this.formNuevo.value).subscribe(cliente => {
          console.log(`modified client`);
          this.back();
        }, error => {
          console.log(`Error edit`);
        });
      }
    } else {
      console.log('3');
      this.markFormTouched();
      console.error('Form is not valid');
    }
  }

}
```

This is my component `service.ts`:

```
const PREFIX = `${environment.baseUrl}/client`;

@Injectable()
export class ClienteService implements IForm<Cliente> {

    constructor(
        private http: HttpClient
    ) {}

    public list(filter: any = {}): Observable<Cliente[]> {
      return this.http.get<Cliente[]>(PREFIX, {params: filter});
    }

    public get(idCliente: number): Observable<Cliente> {
      return this.http.get<Cliente>(`${PREFIX}/${idCliente}`);
    }

    public create(cliente: Cliente): Observable<Cliente> {
      return this.http.post<Cliente>(PREFIX, cliente);
    }

    public edit(cliente: Cliente): Observable<Cliente> {
      return this.http.post<Cliente>(`${PREFIX}/${cliente.id}`, cliente);
    }

    public delete(cliente: number): Observable<Cliente> {
      return this.http.delete<Cliente>(`${PREFIX}/${cliente}`);
    }    
}
```

This is my `component.html`:

```html
    <div class="title">Customer registration</div>
    <mat-divider></mat-divider>
    
    <div fxLayout="column" fxLayoutGap="10px" class="m-3">
    
      <mat-accordion>
        <mat-expansion-panel>
          <mat-expansion-panel-header>New</mat-expansion-panel-header>
          <form [formGroup]="formNuevo">
            <mat-grid-list cols="4" rowHeight="50px" gutterSize="10px">
                <mat-grid-tile>
                  <mat-form-field fxFlex>
                    <input matInput placeholder="First name" formControlName="first_name">
                    <mat-icon matSuffix>person_outline</mat-icon>
                  </mat-form-field>
                </mat-grid-tile>
                <mat-grid-tile>
                  <mat-form-field fxFlex>
                    <input matInput placeholder="Last name" formControlName="last_name">
                  </mat-form-field>
                </mat-grid-tile>
                <mat-grid-tile>
                  <mat-form-field fxFlex>
                    <input matInput placeholder="Phone" formControlName="phone">
                  </mat-form-field>
                </mat-grid-tile>
                <mat-grid-tile [colspan]="3">
                  <div>
                    <button mat-stroked-button (click)="save()">Add</button>
                  </div>
                </mat-grid-tile>
            </mat-grid-list>
          </form>
        </mat-expansion-panel>
      </mat-accordion>
    
      <mat-card class="mat-elevation-z8">
        <mat-table [dataSource]="clients">
    
          <ng-container matColumnDef="id">
            <mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef>ID</mat-header-cell>
            <mat-cell *matCellDef="let clients"> {{clients.id}} </mat-cell>
          </ng-container>
    
          <ng-container matColumnDef="nombre">
            <mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef>First Name</mat-header-cell>
            <mat-cell *matCellDef="let clients"> {{clientes.firstName}} </mat-cell>
          </ng-container>
    
          <ng-container matColumnDef="apellido">
            <mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef>Apellidos</mat-header-cell>
            <mat-cell *matCellDef="let clients"> {{clients.lastName}} </mat-cell>
          </ng-container>
    
          <ng-container matColumnDef="telf">
            <mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef>Telefono</mat-header-cell>
            <mat-cell *matCellDef="let clients"> {{clientes.phone}} </mat-cell>
          </ng-container>
    
          <ng-container matColumnDef="act">
            <mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef>Actions</mat-header-cell>
            <mat-cell *matCellDef="let row">
              <button mat-button><mat-icon>edit</mat-icon></button>
              <button mat-button><mat-icon>delete_forever</mat-icon></button>
            </mat-cell>
          </ng-container>
    
          <mat-header-row *matHeaderRowDef="displayedColumns"></mat-header-row>
          <mat-row *matRowDef="let row; columns: displayedColumns;"></mat-row>
    
        </mat-table>
    
        <mat-paginator [pageSizeOptions]="[5, 10, 20]" showFirstLastButtons></mat-paginator>
      </mat-card>
    
    </div>
```

**My problems**:

1. When I want to add a new record from the form I want to be able to have optional validations and fields. I would need to validate that the phone field is a number and only the first_name field is mandatory and can be repeated.
2. And to edit a record I don't know if it can be done from the same table, that is, when I press the edit button of the `action` column, I can directly modify the data found in that row

Comment: This might be a great help to you: https://angular.io/tutorial/toh-pt6#update-heroes

Comment: @Eugene That is the guide that I am following but I am having a hard time adapting it for my current project

Comment: Sorry, but these are too many questions at the same time. Please, split it up in 4 several questions.

Comment: @Lynx242 All the questions are for the same code so I thought it was better to put them all together. But still what I need are the ts methods to edit, add and delete fields.

Comment: I see. But especially when it comes to filtering it will need a separate issue, as this is a lot of stuff.

Comment: here is the example that you can get help [link](https://stackblitz.com/github/vaibhavphutane/inline-editable-table-angular9?file=src%2Fapp%2Fuser-table%2Fuser-table.component.ts)

Comment: @Lynx242 OK agreed. So I'm going to ask another question with the filtering part. If you could help me with the add, delete and edit methods?

Comment: @neilnikkunilesh The example is fine for the Angular part only, but I am using an API with Spring, so I need to use the service

Comment: I'll get back to you. Promised. But currently I'm at work. ;)

Comment: @Lynx242 Ok ok thanks, I'll keep trying while

Answer (score 1):

**Part I**

So this is how your first problem can be solved.

You can have your own validator. I'll show it here in the TS-file.

***TS***

```
// your first_name is mandatory and your phone number has to be a phone number
this.formNuevo = this.fb.group({
    id: [],
    first_name: new FormControl(null, Validators.required);
    last_name: [],
    phone: new FormControl(null, [this.phoneNumberValidator()])
});

// the validator can be named as you want. It's just an example.
private phoneNumberValidator(): ValidatorFn {
    return (control: AbstractControl): { [key: string]: any } | null => {
      // a guard to prevent field access on undefined or null
      if (!control.value) {
        return null;
      }

      // here comes your code to validate
      const invalid = !this.isPhoneNumber(control.value);

      // the field name notAPhoneNumber is just a suggestion.
      // this is the error's name we'll catch later in the HTML
      return invalid ? {notAPhoneNumber: {value: control.value}} : null;
   };
}

private isPhoneNumber(value: any): boolean {
   // compare whatever you like and return the outcome as boolean
}
```

***HTML***

```
<mat-grid-tile>
    <mat-form-field fxFlex>
        <input matInput placeholder="First name" formControlName="first_name">
        <mat-icon matSuffix>person_outline</mat-icon>

        <!-- mandatory field is empty -->
        <mat-error *ngIf="formNuevo.get('first_name').invalid">
            Please, enter a first name
        </mat-error>
    </mat-form-field>
</mat-grid-tile>

<mat-grid-tile>
    <mat-form-field fxFlex>
        <input matInput placeholder="Phone" formControlName="phone">
        
        <!-- here you get the error message of your validator by its error name -->
        <!-- you get the formControl 'phone' of your formGroup 'formNuevo' to do that -->
        <mat-error *ngIf="formNuevo.get('phone').hasError('notAPhoneNumber')">
            Invalid phone number
        </mat-error>

    </mat-form-field>
</mat-grid-tile>
```

**Part II**

Your second question can be solved like this

***TS***

```
onEdit(client: any): void {
    this.cliente = client;
    this.formNuevo.patchValue(cliente);
}
```

***HTML***

```
<ng-container matColumnDef="act">
    <mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef>Actions</mat-header-cell>
        
    <mat-cell *matCellDef="let client">
        <button mat-button (click)="onEdit(client)"><mat-icon>edit</mat-icon></button>
        <button mat-button><mat-icon>delete_forever</mat-icon></button>
    </mat-cell>
</ng-container>
```

Now the currently clicked client should be displayed in your form above , ready to be edited.

**Part III**

If you want to trigger a validation error programmatically, it is pretty easy as this is also done with the formControl.

***TS***

```
save() {
    // get the formControl's value and compare it with our method
    if (!isPhoneNumber(this.formNuevo.get('phone').value)) {
        // if it is invalid, invoke the error message programmatically
        this.formNuevo.get('phone').setErrors({notAPhoneNumber: {value: true}});

        // stop the entire save-process and leave the method right now.
        return;
    }
}
```

That's all. You now get the error message in the UI and your storing procedure won't finish.

Comment: I can't get the validator to work, right now the function I have is save (), with which I add new records. How could I include the validations in that function?

Comment: You can take validation reference from this [link](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-reactive-form-custom-validation)

Comment: Sorry for answering pretty late. My job was calling. ;)  If this answer fits your requirements I'd really appreciate it if you could mark it as solution. Thx in advance.

Comment: @Lynx242 Sorry for the delay, I have been very busy and I have not been able to connect. The save method works perfect, I still have problems when editing. What I am trying is through the edit button to be able to modify only the fields of that row from their cells, is that possible?

Answer (score 0):

> You can do the following to load the data into table on component load:

```
 ngOnInit(): void {

    // make a service call here 
    this.demoService.getDataFromTable(parameters).subscribe(
      res => {
        let userDetailsArray: UserDetails[] = res;
        const control = this.userTable.get('tableRows') as FormArray;
        this.userDetailsArray.map(userDetailtData => 
      control.push(
        this.fb.group({
          name: [userDetailtData.name, Validators.required],
          email: [userDetailtData.email, [Validators.email, Validators.required]],
          dob: [userDetailtData.dob, [Validators.required]],
          bloodGroup: [userDetailtData.bloodGroup],
          mobNumber: [userDetailtData.mobNumber, [Validators.required, Validators.maxLength(10)]],
          isEditable: [true]
        })
        )
      },
      err => {},
      () => {}
    )
    
    this.touchedRows = [];
    this.userTable = this.fb.group({
      tableRows: this.fb.array([])
    });

  }
```

> For Add new row you can do like below:

```
  addRow() {
    const control =  this.userTable.get('tableRows') as FormArray;
    control.push(this.initiateForm());
  }
```

Comment: I already have the add method, it is the save () method but I need to improve it and add validations. This way I can't do it.

Comment: In the example, I have added validation also.

Comment: Yes, but from the ngOnInit, I need everything related to adding to be done from the save () function I think it is easier to control everything from there and not to do it directly